# Database dropdown array smarty

Tags: php, mysqli, smarty

I'm trying to load drop down options from database, the drop down itself looks like this:

```
    $mainarray = array(
 "Group" => array (
     "Mygroup" => "My Group is",
    "Type" => "dropdown",
    "Options" => GroupA,GroupB,#Here i would like to load Group names from DB
    "Description" => "",
    "Default" => "GroupA",
),
```

How to show all options from mysql?
Big thanks

Comment: so query the db and put the results in a string

Comment: thanks, so it would look something like ` "Options" => data[groups]`?

Answer (score 0):

I would make your options an array and then iterate over them as normal

```
{foreach $options as $opt}
    <option value="{$opt}">{$opt}</option>
{/foreach}
```